# How do I change the Font Style in ACE editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using ACE editor on my page,

```
<script src="ace-builds-master/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/cobalt");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/geco");
</script>
```

By default it is showing a font, I want to change my font to 'Tahoma 10pt'.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To change font you can either add a css rule for `#editor`.
or use

```
editor.setOptions({
  fontFamily: "tahoma",
  fontSize: "10pt"
});
```

But Ace only supports monospace fonts for now, and tahoma isn't monospace, so cursor position will be wrong.

Comment: `setOption()` and `setOptions()` isn't working for me. Only way seems to be changing the actual CSS font-style which can throw off the positioning and sizing of the editor.

Comment: maybe you are using old version, it works on ace.c9.io

Comment: Nope doesn't work for me with ace-editor. When I call setOption("fontFamily") the spacing changes to the new font spacing but the actual font doesn't. Oddly fontSize works.

Comment: Probably you  have a css rule which overrides font-style on elements inside ace.

Answer (score 18):

To my knowledge there is no shortcut to directly change Ace's font family other than `editor.setOptions()`.

However you can set the font size in pixels directly by calling:

```
editor.setFontSize(10) // will set font-size: 10px
```

Comment: but not the token size