# Bold, italic buttons in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror, ace-editor

I use the Ace editor on my website but I'm wondering if there exists any addons to make a simple Markdown toolbar above the editor - just like the one on the Ask question on Stackoverflow.

I've been looking for a stable and active open source project but I couldn't find one.

Comment: I wonder there is anything like this. But I would like to bring into your notice that ace-editor only works with **monospace** fonts properly (without bold/italic property). Even if anyhow any plugin make content bold/italic... It wouldn't perform properly. Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900938/how-do-i-change-the-font-style-in-ace-editor